# HTTP Caching Testing

Tags: http, testing, caching

I have a proxying system that needs to understand the HTTP Cache-Control headers.  The intent is not to perform any actual caching, but to derive tuning information based on the caching characteristics of sets of HTTP requests.  I'm looking for a way to test the system.

I can do spot checking by pushing content from well-known websites or authored sites to make sure that the system is acting correctly.  However, I'd like to expand the pool of test data.

Is there a test suite that enumerates either a set of common or complete caching headers that I can integrate with my software to make sure I'm covering all the bases I need to cover?

Comment: http://www.mnot.net/blog/2007/06/20/proxy_caching mentions http://coad.measurement-factory.com/ (apparently commercial)

Answer (score 0):

I know the Apache HTTPClient (HTTPCore) has a pretty extensive test suite, though I don't know how deeply it goes into the cache stuff.  This is Java, don't know if you care about the language or not.